# How to use flexsearch to search text within the list of .txt files

Tags: node.js, directory, flexsearch

I have a folder wherein I keep multiple `.txt` files. I want to perform `flexsearch` within that folder files and bring the search results. For example, the folder is `'data'`; inside are txt files called `user.txt, cutomer.txt, and admin.txt`. Now, each file has some text inside it. Now the requirement is, that I need to perform the search within the '`data`' folder and bring up the result along with the `.txt` file name. Can somebody guide me on the steps to achieve this? We have this folder in the `node.js` application.